# Android double return

Tags: android, function, return

http://imgur.com/DzTRV2D

In android application i have code like below

```
private boolean isSpinnerNotChoose(Spinner spinner)
{
    if(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(""))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

But after many tries even if condition is completed it firstly enter on return false and later anyway debbugger goes on return true (If something stays after brackets its skipped but return true always is done. In link is image how its look after if is completed.

Anyone can answer me for that situation ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I remember my eclipse debugger hitting steps that `were not actually executed` when stepping thru the code, especially return statemens/closing brackets. Just verify your code returns correct value (by putting breakpoint at invocation and result of your method) and ignore incorrect visual debugging steps.

Comment: Hmmm you have right - after clean project its show steps on `return true` but later its return false anyway :) Thank you also :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better use a boolean and return the boolean once.

The boolean is initially set to **true**.
It will remain **true**, if no match happens.
If there's a match, it will change to **false**.

Then the boolean will be returned (**true if no match happens, false if there's a match**).
No ghost responses.

I also added a `trim()`, to cut away the eventual trailing spaces.

Try:

```
private boolean isSpinnerNotChoose(Spinner spinner)
{
    boolean myValue = true; // default return value
    if(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().trim().equals(""))
    {
        myValue = false;
    }
    return myValue; // return once and for all
}
```

Comment: Its happen even with else statement. If i make like you did it work but if it is return statement it shouldnt return immediately?

Comment: Maybe the string is not "". Try **trimming** it, to cut away the eventual trailing spaces.

Comment: the string is "" because its pass the statement and its enter inside if but after making `return true` it always goes to `return false` and dont understand why.

Comment: Try my solution. The boolean is initially true. It will remain so if no match. If there's a match, it will change to false. Then the boolean will be returned (true if no match, false if there's a match). No false responses

Comment: Ok thank you :) On end i resolve it in one liner - `return !spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("");` but your solution will work perfectly also :)